# VMWare Workstation VLAN - Vyatta routers not able to ping each other

Tags: subnet, vmware-workstation

I have two routers configure to be within the same VLAN - LAN 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1KR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnDtQ.png

And here are the network configurations:

Router 1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0P7Z.png

Router 2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uojaY.png

I'm unable to figure out why *.49 and *.50 can't ping each other and I've been staring at this for ~2 hrs now

Comment: Using public IP addresses that belong to the US military, as you have done here, is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's an isolated network in VMWare for an assignment in a networking class at USAFA. We're to build 3 subnets based on the initial IP block of 11.0.8.0/21, and everything is working for me except this.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring VLANs in VMWare Workstation, make sure that the MAC address of the interface you're configuring in VMWare matches the MAC address shown in VyOS.

What a wasted 2hr.